# Why is the last value in this specific example user input not being taken for my while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, tree, user-input, tree-traversal

I'm facing a bug where, after taking in the user input from a `while` loop, my code does not accept the last value. This bug happens on ONE specific example, and I have no clue why this is happening.

So, for example, the user inputs:

```
7  
3 1 4 0 0 2 0
```

The output is:

```
3140020
```

**HOWEVER**, with the following user input (this is the specific example):

```
7  
3 0 1 0 0 2 0
```

The output should be:

```
3010020
```

**BUT**, the output is instead:

```
301002
```

I can't figure this out at all. The code is attached below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode() : val(0), left(NULL), right(NULL)  {}
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL)  {}
};

TreeNode* construct_tree(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int curr_inp;
    vector<TreeNode*> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> curr_inp;
        cout << curr_inp; // **this is the place of bug**
        if (curr_inp != 0) 
            vec.push_back(new TreeNode(curr_inp));
        else 
            vec.push_back(NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< floor(n/2);i++ )
    {
        vec[i]->left = vec[2*i+1];
        vec[i]->right = vec[2*i+2];
    }
    cout << '\n';
    return vec[0];
}

int main() {
    TreeNode* root = construct_tree();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOveerflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger yourself to see where its behavior differs from what you are expecting? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Small nitpick: your 2 `TreeNode` constructors can be merged together into 1, by supplying a default value for `x`. Also, your code has memory leaks, as it is not `delete`'ing any of the `new`'ed `TreeNode` object.

Comment: @MarzukhAkib Just change `cout << curr_inp;` to `cout << curr_inp<<endl;` and you'll see your last output.

Comment: `<math.h>` -> `<cmath>`. "Owning naked pointers" (i.e. those created with `new`, as in `vec.push_back( new TreeNode( ... ) )`) are frowned upon. Indeed your program is leaking that memory (likely to be saved by the OS' memory protection cleaning up once the program finishes, but your *program* is leaking). Consider using [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead that release their memory automatically. And try to void `using namespace std;`. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in `cout << curr_inp;` The issue is in loop which you used

```
    for(int i = 0; i< floor(n/2);i++ )
    {
        vec[i]->left = vec[2*i+1];
        vec[i]->right = vec[2*i+2];
    }
```

You are trying to call `left` and `right` with null vector

After I added null check there is no segmentation fault

```
    for(int i = 0; i< floor(n/2);i++ )
    {
        if (vec[i]) {
            vec[i]->left = vec[2*i+1];
            vec[i]->right = vec[2*i+2];
        } else {
            cout << "nullptr \n";
        }
    }
```

Now when I use

7
3 0 1 0 0 2 0

I got following ouput

```
7
3 0 1 0 0 2 0
3010020nullptr
```

**Conclusion:** I don't know what your logic is but the issue is because of dereferencing `nullptr`

Comment: that was a very irresponsible thing on my end whoops. thanks though

Comment: there is a up arrow on accepted answer and you can click on it, if you find answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

Your `construct_tree()` function is crashing inside of its 2nd `for` loop. That is preventing the output of the last character written to `cout`, because `cout` output is buffered by default, and the last character is still in the buffer and hasn't been flushed to the console yet when the crash occurs.

`cin` and `cout` are `tie()`'ed together by default, so reading input from `cin` will first implicitly flush `cout`, but there is no read from `cin` being done after the 1st `for` loop's last iteration writes to `cout`.

Try adding a call to `cout << flush` or `cout.flush()` after the 1st `for` loop is done, before entering the 2nd `for` loop.  Or use `cout << curr_inp << flush;` inside the 1st `for` loop. Then you will see the last character displayed.

And then, you need to fix the crash.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did work after adding the cout.flush()
However, why did this bug not happen for other example inputs but specifically this example input?

Comment: That is what debugging is meant to discover.  Clearly your 2nd `for` loop has a logic bug that only manifests for certain inputs and not others.  It is your job to debug your code, not ours.